# Pytest Cache Fixture with Pickle instead of JSON

Tags: python, pytest

I'd like to cache an object I'm creating, which takes a long time to create. However, it's not possible to encode this as a JSON object, so the built-in cache functionality will throw an error. Is there a way to use pickle instead of JSON to cache?

Answer (score 1):

You could pickle your data, convert it to a string, and cache this string. This adds some time for encoding/decoding, but that shouldn't be substantial.
Here is the example from the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html#the-new-config-cache-object) with added pickling:

```
import pickle
import pytest


def expensive_computation():
    print("running expensive computation...")
    return 42


@pytest.fixture
def mydata(request):
    val = request.config.cache.get("example/value", None)
    if val is None:
        val = expensive_computation()
        res = pickle.dumps(val).decode('cp437')
        request.config.cache.set("example/value", res)
    else:
        val = pickle.loads(val.encode('cp437'))
    return val


def test_function(mydata):
    assert mydata == 42
```

Note that I used the old 'cp437' for encoding/decoding as this seems to cover arbitrary bytes (as should any 8-bit encoding), though I'm sure there are better methods. Basically you need to convert arbitrary bytes to string and back by whatever means.